# How to register custom JPA interface using bytebuddy

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, byte-buddy

I need to register a custom interface that extended from JpaRepository.
I found a way using bytebuddy, how to create an interface that extended from JpaRepository, but I didn't find, how to register him as a Bean.

```
  AnnotationDescription name = AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Column.class)
            .define("name", "type")
            .build();

    AnnotationDescription id = AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Id.class)
            .build();

    AnnotationDescription entity = AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Entity.class)
            .build();
    AnnotationDescription table = AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Table.class)
            .define("name", "generated_view")
            .build();

    Class<?> type = new ByteBuddy()
            .subclass(Object.class)
            .name("GeneratedModelX")
            .annotateType(entity)
            .annotateType(table)
            .defineField("id", Integer.class, Visibility.PRIVATE)
            .annotateField(id)
            .defineField("name", String.class, Visibility.PRIVATE)
            .annotateField(name)
            .defineMethod("getId", Integer.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
            .intercept(FieldAccessor.ofBeanProperty())
            .defineMethod("setId", void.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
            .withParameter(Integer.class)
            .intercept(FieldAccessor.ofBeanProperty())
            .defineMethod("getName", String.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
            .intercept(FieldAccessor.ofBeanProperty())
            .defineMethod("setName", void.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
            .withParameter(String.class)
            .intercept(FieldAccessor.ofBeanProperty())
            .make()
            .load(getClass().getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
            .getLoaded();

    AnnotationDescription repositoryAnnotation = AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Repository.class)
            .build();
    
    TypeDescription.Generic genericType = TypeDescription.Generic.Builder
            .parameterizedType(JpaRepository.class, type, Long.class)
            .annotate(repositoryAnnotation)
            .build();

    Class<? extends Object> repository = new ByteBuddy()
            .makeInterface()
            .implement(genericType)
            .name("CustomRepository")
            .make()
            .load(Controller.class.getClassLoader())
            .getLoaded();
```

Comment: How you plan on using thia interface? In theory, I beleive it should be the same way as normal JPA repositories work in Spring world. Since the interface doesn’t exist until its dynamically created, you will need to instruement the invoking service class altering the code injecting this new interface using autowired. Also, you would want to alter existing method or write new method in service class using the new autowired interface. you will also need to make sure the interface exists before instruementing the service class. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have properly created your custom entity and corresponding custom JPA repository - use ByteBuddy to transform the service class autowiring the newly loaded entity.

```
builder = builder.defineField("customRepository", repo, Visibility.PUBLIC)
                 .annotateField(AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Autowired.class)
                        .build());
```

Now, since this is an interface with us not providing any concrete implementation [ Spring will provide proper implementation ], we will need a BeanFactoryPostProcessor.

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class DynamicJpaBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory) throws BeansException {
        BeanDefinitionBuilder beanDefinitionBuilder = BeanDefinitionBuilder
                .rootBeanDefinition(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class).addConstructorArgValue("your.custom.repository.classname");
        ((DefaultListableBeanFactory) configurableListableBeanFactory).registerBeanDefinition("your.custom.repository.classname", beanDefinitionBuilder.getBeanDefinition());

        log.info("Registered the {} bean for {} successfully", JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class.getSimpleName(),
                "your.custom.repository.classname");
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps you. Of-course you will need to transform your service class to add methods utilizing injected repository bean.